# Woocommerce function that triggers jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, function, woocommerce

Iam trying to trigger a popup by simulating a button click with a simple JS function when a product from a specific category is added to the woocommerce cart. I have seen some do it in simmilair functions, but I cant figure this one to work.

I have composed the following function that runs if the category is in cart and if the page is the checkout page:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'check_category_in_cart' );
     
    function check_category_in_cart() {
   $cat_in_cart = false;

   foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

      if ( has_term( 'test', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
         $cat_in_cart = true;
         break;
      }
   }

   if ( $cat_in_cart ) {
 
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
        $('#pop-up').trigger('click');
    });
</script>
   }
 
}
```

This function makes my website not function. Anyone has an idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: What shows up in the Console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout). try the below code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'check_category_in_cart' );
function check_category_in_cart() {

    $cat_in_cart = false;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

        if ( has_term( 'test', 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $cat_in_cart = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( $cat_in_cart ) { ?>
 
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#pop-up').trigger('click');
            }, 10);
        });
    </script>
    <?php }
 
}
```

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
                
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('#pop-up').trigger('click');
    }, 10);

    jQuery(document).on('click','#pop-up',function(){
        alert('trigger');
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="pop-up">popup</button>
```

Comment: Why set timeout when DOM is ready? and why 100mS? No reason for that.

Comment: I have tested in my demo without a set timeout and it's not working.

Comment: Have you tried `$(function() { $('#pop-up').trigger('click');  });`?

Comment: Yes, still does not work. but works fine with `setTimeout`

Answer (score 1):

PHP waits for a php valid code in `<?php ?>` tags, but you are placing JavaScript, so you have to close the PHP tag before `<script>` and open a new one after the `</script>`. Otherwise your jQuery code is fine.

```
   if ( $cat_in_cart ) {
?>
 
<script>
    jQuery(function() { 
        $('#pop-up').trigger('click');
    });
</script>

<?php
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Reason need to check.

1. Maybe Because your id (pop-up) is not placed in your HTML.
2. Maybe your jQuery is not loaded.
3. Check in the console what kind of error you found.
4. your PHP function should properly closed.

```
  if ( $cat_in_cart ) {
 ?>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
        $('#pop-up').trigger('click');
    });
</script>
<?php
   }
```

if all is good then you can try.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
var timeInterVal = setInterval(CheckId, 1000);
CheckId function(){
var id  = $("#pop-up");
if(id.length!=0){
 $('#pop-up').trigger('click');
 clearInterval(timeInterVal);
}
}
});
```

This will work if your Id not found once your id placed then this will stop the timer and trigger pop-up.
Thanks.